# How to dismiss the Progress Dialog in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog

I am facing the issue in dismissing the progress dialog. My issue is when i pressed back from fragment C the progress dialog function is called two times and dismissed two times. Again i gone back to same fragment C and pressed back to come to fragment A ,same progress dialog is called two times but now the only one dialog is dismissed. How to solve this. The process is done in api integration.

The code for moving back from fragment C to fragment A

```
  Fragment_Money_Transfer_Mobile ldf = new  Fragment_Money_Transfer_Mobile();
                        Bundle args = new Bundle();
                        args.putString("number",mobNumber);

                        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, ldf).commit();

                        Fragment_Money_Registration_Form fragment = new   Fragment_Money_Registration_Form();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragment.setArguments(args);
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(  Fragment_Money_Transfer_Mobile.class.getSimpleName() );
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

The code for showing and dismissing the progress dialog

```
  public void showProgress() {
    pDialog = null;
    if (pDialog == null) {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Processing...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        count = 1;
    }

}
public void dismissDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing()){
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
```

I declared the progress dialog globally.

The code for api integration

```
public void getData(){
    showProgress();

        Ion.with(this)
                .load(HelperClass.SERVER_ID + HelperClass.postApis+"/mtvaliatemobileno")
                .setTimeout(HelperClass.timeOut)
                . setHeader(HelperClass.authName,authToken)
                .setHeader(HelperClass.contentName,HelperClass.contentValue)
                .setHeader(HelperClass.secretKeyName,newEncryptedSecretNumber)
                .setHeader(HelperClass.apiKeyName,encryptedDeviceId)
                .setJsonObjectBody(json)
                .asJsonObject()
                .withResponse()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Response<JsonObject>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, Response<JsonObject> result) {
                        dismissDialog();

                        if (e != null) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {
                            if (result != null) {

                                try{
                                    Boolean responceMessage = result.getResult().get("res").getAsBoolean();

                                    JsonObject jsonObject1 = result.getResult().get("CardDetail").getAsJsonObject();
}
}                       
}
```

Please helpe me how to solve this.

Comment: please explain when do you want your progressDialog to be shown and when to be hidden ?

Comment: progress dialog should load before api connection and dialog should dismiss after getting  api responce

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: you can do it in onDestroy override method in andorid